# MacOS X not installing Python 3 via homebrew

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install python 3.7.3 on my machine from 3.6.4 via homebrew. But I must have made a funny installation before because I'd installed Python 3.7.3 successfully on homebrew but when running python3 --version it was still stuck on 3.6.4. I've stupidly deleted the 3.6 source file as you can now see and I don't have any python 3 installation. How do I select the 3.7.3 version that homebrew has installed somewhere on my machine?

```
Python 2.7.15
Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connor$ python3 --version
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: No such file or directory
Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connor$ brew install python3
Warning: python 3.7.3 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.7.3, run `brew reinstall python`
Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connor$
```

Comment: Try taking a look at `/usr/local/Cellar/python3`. My installation has a `3.7.2_2` dir in this. If it's there, then you can point the symlink in `/usr/local/bin/python3` to the file in the `bin` directory.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?